# Verifying proof that a path joining an interior point of $M$ to an exterior point intersects $\partial M$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Can anyone verify this proof, please?

f) if $x_0$ is an interior point and $x_1$ is an exterior point in relation to the set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, then the support of any path with endpoints $x_0, x_1$ intersects the boundary of the set $M$.

**Proof:** Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $x_0$ be an interior point of $M$ and $x_1$ be an exterior point of $M$. Let $\Gamma : [\alpha , \beta ] \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be any path joining $x_0$ and $x_1$, such that $\Gamma (\alpha ) = x_0$ and $\Gamma (\beta ) = x_1$. Let $I = \{\gamma \in [\alpha , \beta ]  : \Gamma (\gamma ) \text{ is an interior point of } M\}$. Since $\Gamma (\beta ) = x_1$ is an exterior point of $M$, $I$ is bounded above. Thus,
$$\xi = \sup (I)$$
exists. We claim that $\Gamma (\xi )$ is boundary point of $M$. Observe that by continuity of $\Gamma$ it follows that $\xi  \ne \max (I)$, that is, $\xi \notin I$.

Indeed, assume $\xi \in I$. Then $\Gamma (\xi )$ is interior point of $M$ and there is some $V^{\varepsilon} ( \Gamma (\xi ))$ symmetrical neighborhood of $\Gamma (\xi )$ contained in $M$. Since $\Gamma$ is continuous, there is some $U^{\delta}(\xi )$ neighborhood of $\xi $ such that $\Gamma (U^{\delta}(\xi )) \subset V^{\varepsilon} ( \Gamma (\xi ))$, which, in particular, implies that images of points $\gamma \in (\xi , \xi + \delta )$ are also interior points of $M$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $\xi$ being $\sup (I)$, cannot belong to $I$.

It remains to show that $\Gamma (\xi )$ is not exterior point of $\xi$. Assume $\Gamma (\xi )$ is an exterior point. Then, by the same reasoning as above, we conclude that theimages of points $\gamma \in (\xi - \delta , \xi ) $ are exterior points, from which follows that points $\gamma \in (\xi - \delta , \xi )$ are upper bounds to $I$, contradicting assumption that $\xi = \sup (I)$.

Hence $\Gamma (\xi )$ is neither interior point of $M$, nor exterior point of $M$, which leaves only possibility of $\Gamma (\xi )$ being boundary point of $M$ as claimed.

Comment: Since seems to be a wordy version of: Since $\Gamma$ is continuous, $\Gamma^{-1}$ of the open sets interior and exterior of $M$ are open in $I$. They are also disjoint and by assumption non-empty. If their union were $I$, this would show that $I$ is not connected. We conclude that there exists $\xi \in I$ such tat $\Gamma(\xi)$ is neither interior nor exterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a any subset with interior $I:=\operatorname{int} M$, its exterior is $E:=\operatorname{int} M^\complement$. As in any metric space

$$\Bbb R^n = I \cup E \cup \partial M$$

where the three sets are pairwise disjoint, $I,U$ are open and $\partial M$ is closed.

So if we have a path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \Bbb R^n$ where $x_0=\gamma(0) \in I$ and $x_1=\gamma(1) \in E$ we cannot have that $\gamma[[0,1]] \cap \partial M = \emptyset$ because that implies that $\{I \cap  \gamma[[0,1]], U \cap \gamma[[0,1]]\}$ would be a disconnection of the connected space $\gamma[[0,1]]$ by disjoint open sets, contradiction. So $\gamma[[0,1]] \cap \partial M \neq \emptyset$ and so there is some $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $\gamma(t) \in \partial M$.

So it holds in any topological space, and any subset $M$ of it, nothing is specific about $\Bbb R^n$ here; no metric is used as well. I only need that $\gamma$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is connected, essentially.

Comment: Oh, that is much simplier than my version. But I guess it is based on topological notions, which my book haven't introduced yet. As it is, is proof correct? I constructed it using basic principles.

Comment: @CommanderVimes It comes down to connectedness of $[0,1]$ which should be known before you do a course like that. You're basically reproving these facts in a special case; the idea is OK in itself.

Comment: Oh, before there was an exercise to prove that E is connected in R implies E is an interval, so I see. Thank you!

Comment: @CommanderVimes You're welcome. Your set $I$ is just $\gamma^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(M)]$ which is open in $[0,1]$ and $\gamma^{-1}[\operatorname{ext}(M)]$ is also open and non-empty, so they cannot cover $[0,1]$ by its connectedness and a missing point has image in $\partial M$. That is simpler.